# Android AppCompat not showing search icon bar only showing overflow

Tags: java, android

I realise that this question has been asked a couple times and I have changed my code to use `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` already but it still doesn't work for me. This is what it's shown in my Android Studio.

[image]

However, once I deployed the app to my mobile I see no items but everything is in the overflow instead.

Here's my code

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.app.MainActivity" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/keepr_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

    <item android:id="@+id/twitter_login"
        android:title="@string/twitter_login"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Comment: item appear in the overflow menu if there is no enough space for items in actionbar. Icon will not be shown in the overflow menu i guess

Comment: But I have nothing in the action bar apart from my logo icon. I guess there should be enough room?

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html Quoting **If there's not enough room for the item in the action bar, it will appear in the action overflow.**

Comment: In fact, it's not recommended to force and use `always`, it's always better to use `ifRoom` there.

Comment: Is there anyway I could determine how much room do I have left to add an icon? I thought there should be enough room because I only use standard android icons.

Comment: Can you try the eclipse with same Code?